# Calling stored procedure from C# code in web application returns PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small

Tags: c#, oracle, stored-procedures, visual-studio-2015, oracle12c

I have created a stored procedure in Oracle 12c and in order to debug the problem I've reduced it to just returning 2 output values. I have tried running the stored procedure in SQL Developer and it returns the values that I'm expecting. However, when I call it from my C# code, I get the following error in Visual Studio 2015:

> ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too
>   small
>
> ORA-06512: at \"*MY_PROCEDURE*", line 32
>
> ORA-06512: at line 1

This is my C# code:

```
Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection oraconn = new Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection("My Connection String");

Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCommand oraComm = new Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCommand("MY_PROCEDURE", oraconn);
oraComm.Parameters.Add("P_REGISTRATION_ID", Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDbType.Int32, ParameterDirection.Input);
oraComm.Parameters.Add("P_OFFICE_ID", Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDbType.Int32, ParameterDirection.Input);
oraComm.Parameters.Add("P_SERIES_ID", Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDbType.Int32, ParameterDirection.Input);
oraComm.Parameters.Add("P_USER_UPDATING", Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDbType.Varchar2, ParameterDirection.Input);
oraComm.Parameters.Add("P_CODE", Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDbType.Varchar2, ParameterDirection.Output);
oraComm.Parameters.Add("P_NUM", Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDbType.Int32, ParameterDirection.Output);

oraComm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

oraconn.Open();
oraComm.ExecuteNonQuery();

var ticketCode = oraComm.Parameters["P_CODE"].ToString();
var ticketNum = oraComm.Parameters["P_NUM"].ToString();
```

Here is the stored procedure - I've reduced it to just provide values to the output parameters and I still get the same error even with that:

```
PROCEDURE MY_PROCEDURE(
P_REGISTRATION_ID      IN  NUMBER,
P_OFFICE_ID            IN  NUMBER,
P_SERIES_ID            IN  NUMBER,
P_USER_UPDATING        IN  VARCHAR2,
P_CODE          OUT VARCHAR2,
P_NUM           OUT NUMBER) 
AS
BEGIN    
  P_CODE := 'AA';
  P_NUM := 1;
END INS_REGISTRATION_QS_PR;
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. I feel like I'm just missing something small to fix it.

Comment: First off, the output parameter names are `P_CODE` and `P_NUM`, but you're assigning values to `P_TICKET_CODE` and `P_TICKET_NUM`, so how could this have compiled?

Comment: I forgot to change that part. It was supposed to be P_CODE and P_NUM. I've made the adjustments in the question.

Comment: Can you please show your original procedure `MY_PROCEDURE` (according error message the error appears at line 32, but your procedure does not have so many lines)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea why this worked, but Bob's solution gave me an idea. I decided to just break up the parameter code in my C# code instead of using the constructor and it worked.

Here's the code:

```
Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleParameter tcParam = new Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleParameter();
        tcParam.ParameterName = "P_CODE";
        tcParam.OracleDbType = Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDbType.Varchar2;
        tcParam.Size = 10;
        tcParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
        oraComm.Parameters.Add(tcParam);
```

Thanks again for all the replies.

Answer (score 2):

One problem I can see is that the string output parameter doesn't have a max length set. Change the setup of the P_CODE parameter in the C# code to

```
oraComm.Parameters.Add("P_CODE", 
                       Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDbType.Varchar2, 
                       32767,
                       ParameterDirection.Output);
```

Best of luck.

Comment: Thank you. I tried your solution and unfortunately I still received the same error message.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
oraComm.Parameters.Add("P_CODE", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 32767, null, ParameterDirection.Output);
oraComm.Parameters["P_CODE"].DbType = DbType.String;
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried your solution and it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
command.Parameters.Add("keys", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 32767).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
```

It worked for me !